# error:conversion to non scalar type

Tags: c++

So i've looked at other peoples code with the same problem and it's usually an issue with missing pointers, I can't seem to fix this,

```
**error: conversion from 
`glm::vec2 {aka glm::detail::tvec2<float, (glm::precision)0u>}` to non-scalar type `glm::vec3 {aka glm::detail::tvec3<float, (glm::precision)0u>}` requested.**

#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include "graphics.h"
#include "mesh.h"
#include "shader.h"
#include "texture.h"

int main(){

CreateWindow(800, 600, "Hello World!");

glm::vec3 vertices[] = {glm::vec3(-0.5, -0.5, 0), glm::vec2(0, 0),
                        glm::vec3(0, 0.5, 0), glm::vec2(0.5, 1.0),
                        glm::vec3(0.5, -0.5, 0), glm::vec2(1.0, 0),
                       };

CreateMesh(vertices, (sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(vertices[0])));
initialiseShader("./res/basicShader");
initialiseTexture("./res/bricks.jpg");
```

The code:

```
while(!IsClosed()){
    Clear(0.0f, 0.15f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

    Bind();

    Bind(0);

    Draw();

    Update();
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: At what line is the error given?

Comment: line 15 at the end of this set of code

glm::vec3 vertices[] = {glm::vec3(-0.5, -0.5, 0), glm::vec2(0, 0),
                        glm::vec3(0, 0.5, 0), glm::vec2(0.5, 1.0),
                        glm::vec3(0.5, -0.5, 0), glm::vec2(1.0, 0),
                       };

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to construct `vertices`, which is an array of `glm::vec3`, from a mixture of `glm::vec3` and `glm::vec2`.

Comment: do you know how I could convert the glm::vec2 into glm::vec 3 or another fix?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to do. Why do you have `glm::vec2` there in the first place?